# FileChannel.size() guaranteed to return correct size (including pending updates) in Sun JVM?

Tags: java, file, file-io

In the Sun JVM, is the FileChannel.size() method guaranteed to return the correct size of the file, including any pending updates? In other words, is the following test guaranteed to pass (assuming that nothing else is writing to the file):

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
fileChannel.write(buffer);
long size1 = fileChannel.size();
fileChannel.force(true);
long size2 = fileChannel.size();
assertEquals(size1, size2);
```

Answer (score 3):

No strong guarantees, imo. It'd depend on the OS. But from what I see the sizes shall be equal...

More:

force(true) on linux  is implemented via [fsync(fd)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fsync.2.html), on windows it is [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However you do not check if write has finished writing (`buffer.hasRemaining()`), I am not sure if any of impl allow async writes [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Linux](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html)

Comment: Good point re. buffer.hasRemaining(). However, this isn't actual code, just an example, so I'm assuming that some data gets written at the point at which I call write(buffer).

Comment: generally `force()` asks the OS to flush its own buffers to the hardware, so it shall no effect on `size()` function which operates on the same file descriptor. I can assume it'd be true (the size before force and after), though.