# Is there a way to get file size having only FileDescriptor?

Tags: java, file, file-descriptor

Let's assume that I have a valid Java `FileDescriptor` which I got in this way:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/some/path/to/file.txt");
FileDescriptor fd = is.getFD();
```

Now please forget that I know file path. The only thing I have is a `FileDescriptor`. Is there a **simple way** to know the file size?
For now I've checked that:

1. `FileDescriptor` has `valid()` method which can tell me if it's valid
   but doesn't have `length()` or `size()` functionality.
2. `FileInputStream` doesn't return the path and since it's a stream it
   obviously won't tell me the file size.
3. `File` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
   which has `length()` method doesn't have a constructor able to handle
   FileDescriptor.

I know that I could read whole stream and sum the length but I don't consider it as **simple way**.

Comment: Have you tried inputStream.available()?

Comment: No because API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) states that function returns: an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking or 0 when it reaches the end of the input stream.

Comment: @Stefan Would it be reliable? It's an estimate and only covers non-blocking. I guess on a file it might be ok but I don't think there are any guarantees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way would be to get the size of the `FileChannel` ([refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5342668/1743880)):

```
public long getSize(FileDescriptor fd) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fd)) {
        return fis.getChannel().size();
    }
}
```

However, as said the linked question, there is no strong guarantee that this will work for all OS.

The only sure and compatible way is to read the content of the stream, like you said in your question.

Comment: a general question: what's the difference on using `getChannel().size()` and `available()`?

Comment: @nafas I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23147743/1743880) covers it.

Comment: Thanks it works in my case. Btw. do you see any particular reason why File doesn't have constructor able to handle FileDescriptor?

Comment: @user1723095 `File` represents a single path that may or may not point to an existing file. `FileDescriptor` always points to an existing file but the file may exist under multiple paths.

Comment: @Tunaki I know that available can return a bad result, but is `getChannel().size()` always working as it should, returning the size of the file?